# What kind of noun is the 'Royal College of Surgeons'?

Tags: nouns, possessives

Would it just be considered a compound noun or is there another name for it?

And even though surgeons is plural, would it still take 's to make the possessive (i.e. the Royal College of Surgeons's dinner party vs the Royal College of Surgeons' dinner party)?

Comment: It's not a noun, it's a noun phrase. Note that **-'s** can well be added to a nominal phrase as a whole, sometimes it can be added even to a whole clause: "the girl I saw yesterday's phone number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a proper name - an expression which has been conventionally adopted as the name of a particular entity (CaGEL p515). These differ from proper nouns in that they have the status of noun phrases: they are not just a single noun like *Thames* which cannot be used in places where a noun phrase would be required like subject or object.

When in the genitive case, proper names with post-head dependents are   phrasal genitives because the genitive marking is located on the last word of the post head dependent *of Surgeons*, and not on the head noun *College* (CaGEL p479).

Since the genitive is associated with the regular noun *surgeons*, the bare genitive is obligatory - just the apostrophe with no *s* following (CaGEL p481).

Comment: Thanks--just to confirm, your comment that since the genitive is associated with surgeons, it would just be an apostrophe, that isn't specific to American English?

Also, I tried to find your reference--CaGEL--but had no luck, can you clarify the source?

Comment: CaGEL is the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey Pullum and collaborators. The two main authors are British linguists so it's not just for American English.

Comment: _Sonny Stewart and the Dynamos_ is a similar example. I assume that _The Legion and the Lioness_ would take apostrophe-s were one to insist on using the Saxon genitive. // What does CGEL call the usage of _mens_ say in _working mens clubs_ (now more common, I believe, than the older apostrophised version)?